# How to return a property with IHttpActionResult in Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, post, asp.net-web-api

I have a model class like so (generated from EF):

```
public partial class Point
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int First { get; set; }
    public int Second { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

and a Post method (which is called from Angular) in my controller (ApiController) like so:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Point))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostPoint(Point points)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        points.Total = points.First + points.Second;

        db.ScoreBoard.Add(points);

        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = points.Id }, points);
    }
```

This will return the whole `points` object and my `POST` call will have a `Response` with all the properties of that object.

Now what I want to do is to return only the `Total` property and so I tried to changed the return of the `PostPoint` to :

```
return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = points.Id }, points.Total);
```

Doing this however will return an empty `Response` to the `POST` call from Angular.

The Angular post-method looks like this:

```
this.post = function (Point) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/api/PointsAPI",
        data: JSON.stringify(Point)
    });
    return request;
}
```

How would I go about only returning the `Total` property of the `points`object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be empty because you are returning a primitive data type. Your Total property is just a number so when angular parses the response it expects an object and all it sees is "2" (if your Total was 2). So, wrap it in an object and angular will be able to parse it.

```
return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = points.Id }, new { points.Total });
```

This will return `{ "Total" : 2 }` in your body. Now angular will have an object with a Total property.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It makes so much sense now.